# Clustering across layers

Tags: openlayers-3

I know how to create clustering inside one layer. It works fine. But is there any way to create clustering across different layers that e.g. points from different layers be not one on each other?

Lets look on this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vnpq1qbu/1/

```
var count = 10000;
var features = new Array(count);
var e = 4500000;
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
  features[i] = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
}

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 40,
  source: source
});

var styleCache = {};
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    var size = feature.get('features').length;
    var style = styleCache[size];
    if (!style) {
      style = [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 10,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff'
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#3399CC'
          })
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: "frs" + size.toString(),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#fff'
          })
        })
      })];
      styleCache[size] = style;
    }
    return style;
  }
});



var count2 = 10000;
var features2 = new Array(count);
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
  features2[i] = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
}

var source2 = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features2
});

var clusterSource2 = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 40,
  source: source2
});

var styleCache2 = {};
var clusters2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource2,
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    var size = feature.get('features').length;
    var style = styleCache2[size];
    if (!style) {
      style = [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 10,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ddd'
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#ff0000'
          })
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: "ola" + size.toString(),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#aaa'
          })
        })
      })];
      styleCache2[size] = style;
    }
    return style;
  }
});




var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
});

var raw = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, clusters, clusters2],
  renderer: 'canvas',
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Blue and red are different layers and clustering is for each layers separately. I would like to have clustering for all points no matter in what layer they are. Or maybe the only solution is to add all points into one layer? But I really want to avoid it.

Comment: To get an answer, you should probably clarify whether you want to include features from both layers in the same clusters, or if you want separate red and blue clusters.

Comment: @ahocevar I would like to keep red and blue points in different layers because I have a lot of other logic there. But do you want to try to tell me that I can use one cluster as a source for two layers?

Comment: Not directly, but it is easy to combine two vector sources into another source which could be the source for your cluster layer. That would work by just listening to the `addfeature` and `removefeature` events of the original sources.